# Invalid reference to 'this' expression. Animation Controller

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I have this error when I try to load Animation Controller. This problem shows when I changed my SDK 2.15.0 to 2.7.0. Red line in "vsync: this" This is my code:

main.dart

```
class SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final AnimationController _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  String _connectionStatus = 'unKnown';
  final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();
  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> connectivitySubscription;
  Future<void> _initPackageInfo() async {
    final info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
    setState(() {
      packageInfo = info;
    });
  }
```

SplashScreen.dart

```
AnimationController animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5));
```

the error is vsync: this. Red line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just insert a `late` before assigning a **final** variable like this:

```
late final AnimationController _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500));
```

If you need explanation, comment below.